# How can I send a message when my app is killed(android)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, kill

Under normal circumstances,if app is killed,i can not do anything.But I have a demand is that when my app is killed,i need to tell server app is dead.But when i initiative to kill my app or my app is recycled by system,i can not do anything and i do not how to tell server app is killed.What i know is to call jni,but i don't know how to write jni code.have anyone know it?

Comment: Not sure, if this will meet your requirements, but you could implement a Socket connection to your server (for example with socket.io). Once the App is killed the socket connection will automatically close and your server will know the app is dead.

Comment: Right, the default Application system will just kill the process and not notify the app that it is being closed (hence not making it possible to execute user code). What you could do is to use a Service to monitor the state of the app.

Comment: @evident if the app getting killed will the service of the app work???

Comment: tbh, I am not sure if it will as well, but for services there is a way to have them automatically restart. Hence you should be able to track the app state then

Comment: Take a look at: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/21356/uncaughtexception

Answer (score 0):

Try using daemon. In that case, you can turn your java process into daemon and finish main one.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo022

In general, you want to demonize your native code.

```
...
...
int demonize() {
  int pid = fork();
  switch ( pid ) {
    case -1:
      return (-1);
    case 0:
      break;
    default:
      return pid;
  }
  return 0;
}
...
...
int pid = demonize();

if( pid == 0 ) {
  while(1) {
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(fid, "daemon\n");
    fflush( fid );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does that address the question?  What happens when your daemon is killed?

Comment: Question was - "Under normal circumstances,if app is killed,i can not do anything (...) when my app is killed,i need to tell server app is dead.". The solution above is an answer to that question. By running daemon you can monitor the app and let server know when it is killed.